# SSH login tries to execute commands that does not exist

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd

I upgraded a server from Debian 9 to 10 and after a reboot at the next SSH login I get the following errors :

```
-bash: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash: No such file or directory
-bash: daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
-bash: bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
-bash: sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
-bash: sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync: No such file or directory
-bash: games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
-bash: man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
-bash: lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
-bash: mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
-bash: news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
```

It looks like something is corrupted somewhere, since those looks like what is inside /etc/passwd and the content gets executed.

What does an ssh login does when opening a session that could try to execute the above? I checked /etc/profile and everything looks quite standard, I tried to remove my ~/.bashrc but nothing change.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bash [executes a number of files on startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) depending on a number of factors, such as whether it is an interactive or login shell, etc. Some of the additional files include `$HOME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.profile` and `$HOME/.bash_login`.

Comment: In addition, there are [other, less documented paths](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/config-top.h#n100) sourced by Bash and configurable at compile-time (so dependant on the maintainer in the particular distribution), such as `SYS_BASHRC`, which defaults to _/etc/bash.bashrc_, and so on. For example, [Artix Linux](https://gitea.artixlinux.org/packages/bash/src/commit/af358952fe09a713fc149c90c4b2bb97499127d6/PKGBUILD#L52) sets `SYS_BASHRC` to _/etc/bash/bashrc_.

Comment: Does this happen for every user? Does it only happen when you log in using SSH? Does it also happen when you switch to another user with "sudo -u user -l"? Does the error cause the login to fail, or does the shell become unusable in some way? Does this happen if you start "bash -l" and/or "bash"? Does it affect other shells, like fish or zsh?

Comment: Does the error always include the user accounts up to the "news" account, or did you truncate the output? Is that tho whole of the output, or did you omit any lines that did not look like error messages?

Comment: If you login at the console, ie not using ssh, do you get the same behavior?  If you login as another user, do you get the same behavior?  If you login as another user and then switch to your account ("su username" as well as "su - username" , do you get the same behavior?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is attempting to execute /etc/passwd *or a copy thereof*.

Really, the first course of action is to fsck your disks and revert to your pre-upgrade backup:

1. This should be the most reliable path to a known good state
2. You don't know that the corruption is limited to this one action
3. It should allow you to confirm that the issue arose a result of the upgrade

....but to isolate the issue further....

sshd/ssh don't execute anything other then the shell (bash in this case). The shell will execute various file at start up, depending on how it has been invoked - see link in @Vilinkameni's comment.

I don't have either a Debian 9 or 10 host handy to check, but often the default script in /etc/profile will run each of the scripts in /etc/profile.d/ so add that to the list of things you should be checking.

Instrumenting /etc/profile will allow you to see WHERE in the chain of operations the errant behaviour occurs. What you see above is being written to STDERR - your code should also write there (stdout and stderr are not necessarily synchronized):

```
echo "DEBUG: $BASH_SOURCE[0] : $LINENO" >&2
```

Debian 10 was EOL over 6 months ago, Debian 9 20 months ago.

Comment: What makes you think the user needs to do a `fsck`. What _exactly_ should the user restore from backups, and why?

Comment: OP suspects corruption as a cause. On a sensibly configured host, fsck'ing the root partition should take a couple of minutes vs waiting for the next issue to occur.

Comment: I don't know HOW OP backs up - but given that OP considers the debian upgrade as a possible trigger, contributory factor, it should be obvious what needs to be restored.

Comment: Well, then they possibly get back to their old outdated system, and they need to do the upgrade again, which will (if it's the upgrade's fault) put the system into the same state again.  IMO, it would be better to diagnose the issue and fix it, and then proceed with further upgrades until they reach a modern Debian installation.  For all we know, the upgrade may well be a red herring.  I have not seen this issue before on systems where it's been the fault of performing a Debian upgrade.

Comment: Did you just come here to argue? Yes, it *may* put the system into the same state again - at which point OP KNOWS what caused the issue - OTOH if he/she previously fscked and found issues but the upgrade works then he knows the upgrade was not the cause. If you have a constructive contribution, then please post your own answer.

Comment: I just wanted you to say why you think a `fsck` and restore from backup would be the go-to action in this case. You mentioned a "corruption". Why would a system upgrade cause a filesystem corruption? Without knowing that this is indeed a common thing that happens when you update a Debian 9 system to 10 (or when you do system upgrades in general), those actions seems fetched from thin air.  The rest of your answer reads well and is good suggestions for figuring out what might be wrong, it's just that initial 3rd of the text that seems a bit odd.

Comment: Cause may have been corruption pre-dating upgrade. If you think there is a better approach for the OP to get their system back functioning as quickly and safely as possible, given their apparent skills level, please post your own answer.

Comment: The OP didn't indicate that the filesystem is corrupted. The question is about the SSH login, which for some reason feeds what looks to be a passwd file to the shell.

Comment: "It looks like something is corrupted somewhere"

Comment: Nonetheless, there is no indication of a filesystem corruption. The OP used an unfortunate wording in the sentence which you quoted to state generically that there is some kind of an issue. What is much more likely is the misconfiguration of SSH server or client, though it could be a maintainer's error during compilation of one of the relevant packages if it manifested after an upgrade (see my comments to OP's posts).

Comment: It is improbable - but the probability x cost of doing the fsck pre-emptively rather than discovering filesystem issues *AFTER* other remediations makes this a no-brainer.